# Need detailed explanation for Memoize implementation in Swift (WWDC 14, session 404)

Tags: swift

Dave Abrahams presents a very interesting version of memoize ([WWDC 2014 Session 404: Advanced Swift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g44U1937o0g#t=35m15s)):

```
func Memoize<T:Hashable, U> (body: (T -> U, T ) -> U ) -> (T) -> U {

      var memo = Dictionary <T, U> ()

      var result: (T -> U)!

      result = { x in
            if let q = memo[x] { return q }
            let r = body(result, x)
            memo[x] = r
            return r
      }

      return result
}

let factorial = Memoize { (factorial, x) in
                x == 0 ? 1 : x * factorial(x - 1)
        }
```

=====
This works great even for recursive functions. I am having difficulty in actually understanding this. Any expert explanation would greatly help.

**Update: using local functions:**

Swift 2's local functions allow **Memoize** to be implemented more cleanly.

Swift 3 requires the `@noescaping` annotation; otherwise it complains: "Declaration closing over non-escaping parameter `body` may allow it to escape."

```
func Memoize<T:Hashable, U> (body: @escaping ((T) -> U, T ) -> U ) -> (T) -> U {

    var memo = Dictionary <T, U> ()

    func result(x : T) -> U {
        if let q = memo[x] { return q }
        let r = body(result, x)
        memo[x] = r
        return r
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: Your question inspired me to write a post about the subject https://medium.com/@mvxlr/swift-memoize-walk-through-c5224a558194#.sl4bfon3k

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually a more or less completely standard implementation of `memoize`. You keep a map (here, a dictionary) of inputs and outputs. If we already have the input in the dictionary, look it up and return the output. If we don't, calculate it, store it in the dictionary, and return it.

The `memoize` function only has to be called once, because it transforms any function (of the proper type) into a memoized version of that function. From then on, you just call the memoized version. So this is a function that accepts a function as parameter and returns a new function as result. The returned function simply wraps a call to the original function in the memoization that I described in the preceding paragraph.

It's hard to know what else to tell you, because I don't know what part you're finding hard to understand. My book goes into great detail on how functions get passed around in Swift. If you don't understand the notion of passing a function as parameter to a function, read [this section](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_as_value). If you don't understand the notion of a function returning a function, read [this section](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_returning_function).

Swift has closures, so we get to maintain the dictionary in the environment space of the returned function (by defining it outside the returned function, so that it is captured). If that's what you're finding hard to understand, here's a [simpler example](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_closure_preserving_its_captured_environment) of that.

Comment: Thank you Matt. This explanation helps. Also one hard thing there to understand is the declaration of the  var result: (T -> U)! .  What is the motivation to declare it thusly?

Comment: He goes into some detail on that, if I recall correctly. He's just working around some odd limitation of the Swift language (at the time the talk was given).

Comment: Yeah, looks like that is the way to ensure using a variable before it is initialised. For instance, we tend to use that result variable in the block that gets reassigned to result itself.

Comment: Matt, I have edited my question with a clean implementation using local functions. this makes it much easier to read the code.

Comment: You're exactly correct - local functions cannot be self-referential until Swift 2.0, so he has to work around that (rather cleverly). In Swift 2.0, local functions can be self-referential, mutually referential, and even recursive.