# Swift Algorithm calculate possible way to reach destination

Tags: swift, algorithm

I'm writing an algorithm to calculate possible number of way to arrive at the destination which is at n steps away from starting point given that each move can be a random number of 1 to 6 steps.

Here is an outline of the algorithm:

```
 f(1) = 1 // when total number of block is 1, there is 1 way to reach the goal
 f(2) = 2 // when total number of block is 2, there is 2 ways to reach the goal, such as 1+1 and 2
 f(3) = 5 // when total number of block is 3, there is 5 ways to reach the goal
 f(4) = 8 // when total number of block is 3, there is 5 ways to reach the goal
 f(5) = 14 // when total number of block is 3, there is 5 ways to reach the goal
 f(6) = 25 // when total number of block is 3, there is 5 ways to reach the goal

 // when total number of block is 7, you may rolled 1~6 at 1st time
 // then you have 7-1 ~ 7-6 block for the rest, thus 
 f(7) = f(7-1) + f(7-2) + f(7-3) + f(7-4) + f(7-5) + f(7-6) 

 // With MI, when total number of block is n, then
 f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3) + f(n-4) + f(n-5) + f(n-6)
```

I manage to get the function

```
func probabilityToGoal(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    if n == 1 {return 1}
    if n == 2 {return 2}
    if n == 3 {return 5}
    if n == 4 {return 8}
    if n == 5 {return 14}
    if n == 6 {return 25}

    return probabilityToGoal(n-1)
         + probabilityToGoal(n-2)
         + probabilityToGoal(n-3)
         + probabilityToGoal(n-4)
         + probabilityToGoal(n-5)
         + probabilityToGoal(n-6)
}
```

But the problem is the function only run for small value (less than 50) How can we achieve the above algorithm in swift 3 for big value (for example n = 610).

Comment: Are you sure that f(3)=5 and f(5)=14?

Comment: @MartinR yeah, I think `f(3) = 4` (`1 1 1`, `1 2`, `2 1`, `3`)

Comment: Thanks should be f(3) = 4. is f(5) = 14 correct?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh: f(5) = 14 is *not* correct.

Comment: f(5) should be 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to employ a technique called dynamic programming.

The idea is to prune entire branches of the call tree by avoiding recursive calls for values that have already been computed.

A dictionary is used to store a mapping from inputs to outputs. Each time a new recursive call is about to be done, the dictionary is first checked to see if it already contains the output for the desired input. If it exists, it's used, otherwise recursion is used to obtain the result. Once computed, the result is then stored in the dictionary for future use.

Here's what that would look like:

```
var cache = [Int: Int]()

func probabilityToGoal(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    if n == 1 { return 1 }
    if n == 2 { return 2 }
    if n == 3 { return 5 }
    if n == 4 { return 8 }
    if n == 5 { return 14 }
    if n == 6 { return 25 }

    if let existingValue = cache[n] {
        // result for n is already known, just return it
        return existingValue
    }

    let newValue = probabilityToGoal(n-1)
                 + probabilityToGoal(n-2)
                 + probabilityToGoal(n-3)
                 + probabilityToGoal(n-4)
                 + probabilityToGoal(n-5)
                 + probabilityToGoal(n-6)

    cache[n] = newValue // store result for future result

    return newValue
}

print(probabilityToGoal(64))
```

Keep in mind that this won't work n ≥ 64, because it overflows the 64 bit `Int` (on 64 Bit systems).

Also, an iterative solution will perform much faster, as it removes recursion overhead and allows you to use an Array instead of a Dictionary:

```
var cache = [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 14,25]

func probabilityToGoal2(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    cache.reserveCapacity(n)
    for i in stride(from: n, to: 6, by: +1) {
            let r1 = cache[i - 1] + cache[i - 2]
            let r2 = cache[i - 3] + cache[i - 4]
            let r3 = cache[i - 5] + cache[i - 6]
            cache.append(r1 + r2 + r3)
    }

    return cache[n]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yrs help. That mean we can only run function for n<=64? is there any bigger Int can be used?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh You can use something like https://github.com/lorentey/BigInt

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh Maybe you can use https://github.com/lorentey/BigInt instead of `Int` and achieve the result for higher numbers.

Comment: The caching can also be done by creating a "memoizing" function, as described in WWDC 2014 Session 404: Advanced Swift.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129211/need-detailed-explanation-for-memoize-implementation-in-swift-wwdc-14-session.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, I've seen that, it's **really** cool. But I specifically chose to take a more ground up approach, and show how the design comes about. Gotta walk before you can make Memoization-as-a-Restful-YAML-microservice-API-provider-factory :p

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to mention it. – Btw, for the iterative version you can use a 6-element array instead of a dictionary as cache.

Comment: @MartinR Good one, I overlooked that

Comment: @MartinR Fun fact, `7...n` crashes when `n > 7`, so you have to use `1...n where n > 7`. However, `stride(from: 7, to: n, by: +1)` allows the `to` to be smaller than the `from` ... interesting